# SQL/ORACLE- FOREIGN KEY using two columns from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create an table in SQL*Plus that consults two columns from another table. For example,

If table A looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(Customer_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
NAME Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PHONE Varchar(12) NOT NULL,
OUTSTANDING_FEES Varchar(10) NULL);
```

And if my table B looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Fees
(Fee_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FEE_TYPE Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID int NOT NULL);
```

I want to populate the OUTSTANDING_FEES in table A with the AMOUNT in table B, where the CUSTOMER_ID matches among the tables. For my purposes I can assume that any single Customer_ID in table B will only appear once in the table.

I've tried creating both tables, with the table A OUTSTANDING_FEES field being null and then making it a FOREIGN KEY that references table B's AMOUNT field, but it's not working since I need to make sure it also cross references the CUSTOMER_ID fields in both tables.

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: You can not create foreign key reffering to non primary key column.

Comment: Surely there will be many fees per customer over time; and those will be paid at some point? So this seems flawed. If you want to see the *outstanding* fees for customer then you would need to look at and aggregate all fees and payments. It it still probably wouldn't be sensible to try to record the result in the parent table (e.g. via a trigger when fee added or paid). It would be simpler/safer to have a view that joins the relevant tables, which will always be up-to-date.

Comment: @tejash - *"You can not create foreign key reffering to non primary key column"*. Not quite accurate. We can build foreign keys which reference unique constraints, which is less common than referencing primary keys but it has its use cases.

Comment: Defining OUTSTANDING_FEES and AMOUNT as `varchar2` columns is bad data modelling as both are surely intended to be numeric (monetary) values. Good practice is always to use the most appropriate datatype for the attribute we're modelling.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create foreign key on a non-primary column from another table(s). 
You'll have to create FK on FEE_ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
Customer_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
NAME Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PHONE Varchar(12) NOT NULL,
OUTSTANDING_FEES Varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer_Fees(FEE_ID)
);
```

You can use AMOUNT field in your select clause.

```
Select A.Customer_ID,B.AMOUNT from Customers A Join Customer_Fees B
on A.OUTSTANDING_FEES = B.FEE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks django, that satisfied what i was trying to do

Comment: If we are going to model OUTSTANDING_FEES as a foreign key it should have the same datatype as the referenced column: FEE_ID is numeric therefore it is wrong to define OUTSTANDING_FEES as a string. But also I would strongly argue this version of the data model is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with the data model posed in the question.

1. Defining OUTSTANDING_FEES and AMOUNT as `varchar2`columns is bad data modelling as both are surely intended to be numeric (monetary) values. Good practice is always to use the most appropriate datatype for the attribute we're modelling.
2. Building a foreign key between OUTSTANDING_FEES and AMOUNT is wrong because they are not unique identifiers. The amount of money owed by one customer can be the same as the amount of money owed by any other - even all - customers (at the start of term all students owe the same amount of tuition fees). So, a foreign which *"references the CUSTOMER_ID fields in both tables"* is all that is needed.
3. The data model doesn't provide any attribute which allows us to distinguish between fees which have been paid and fees which haven't.
4. The questioner states that *"I can assume that any single Customer_ID in table B will only appear once in the table"* but in real life we would expect Customers to have multiple fee records, unpaid and paid. Why not model that? Otherwise if there is truly a 1:1 relationship between Customer and Fee then there is no need for two tables.

So, here is an improved model. It uses proper datatype for monetary values; it enforces the foreign key between the two tables using CUSTOMER_ID; consequently it supports a one-to-many relationship between Customer and Fee; finally it tracks paid and unpaid fees.

```
create table customers
( customer_id integer      not null constraint cust_pk primary key
, name        varchar2(30) not null
, phone       varchar2(12) not null
)
/

create table customer_fees
( fee_id       integer      not null constraint fees_pk primary key
, fee_type     varchar2(20) not null
, amount       number       not null
, invoice_date date         not null
, paid_date    date             null
, customer_id  integer      not null constraint fees_cust_fk references customers 
)
/
```

Ah, but what about OUTSTANDING_FEES? Well, that information is derivable from the data in the two tables. There are many ways of writing this query, this approach is just a choice:

```
select cust.customer_id
       , cust.name
       , cust.phone
       , fees.outstanding_fees
from   customers cust
       left outer join 
        ( select fees.customer_id
               , sum(case when fees.paid_date is null then fees.amount 
                     else 0 end) as outstanding_fees
          from customer_fees fees
          group by fees.customer_id ) fees on fees.customer_id = cust.customer_id

/
```

Generally it is better to calculate aggregated values on demand rather than re-calculate them in every transaction. It scales better, certainly with OLTP volumes of data; the physics of a data warehouse is different, but I don't think that's what we're dealing with in this case.